# Deploy Data files in different location

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I'm having a problem that I need to avoid to enforce the app to not ask for UAC admin privilage to access local xml files that deployed to the same folder located in ProgramFiles.  I need to deploy it to different location where no admin priviliage required. plus how to access the same location path via code.